# data transformation for model fitting: from decibels to power

Tags: modeling, data-transformation

I would like to fit a model to a dataset, namely, I would like to model the response of a system to changes in sound intensity in dB.

The system displays a sigmoidal change in its response with increasing Sound to Noise ratio in dB which I want to model and whose parameters I want to estimate.

I have my recorded data Y(SNR) with several SNRs in dB: -3dB, -5dB, -7dB, and -Inf, which is a "no sound" condition.

I can't have -Inf as a predictor variable, I thought I would thus backtransform everything into power.

SNR in dB is equal to 10*log10(I1/I0) with I1 being the sound intensity I manipulated and I0 the noise that we did not measure but kept constant.

I thought I would back transform everything in actual intensity by transforming X in dB into x in power: x = 10^(X/10), and y = 10^(Y/10).

Is that the correct way to go? Will I be able to interpret my parameters by simply 10*log10(param)?

Comment: What were the shape before and after this transformation, and what do you think is the problem with the shape now that was not present before?

Comment: Actually this was not the best phrasing for my question, I changed it a bit to make it more accurate.